# Post a video by URL on facebook using the facebook graph API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook page, and I am trying to upload a video to it that is already hosted on my servers. 
I need to do this via javascript, and all I have is the src link (something like `https://cdn.whodaman.net/Q45rt7y.mp4`) of the video. Being the administrator, I have all required permissions (`publish_stream, manage_pages`).

The [facebook api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) says that I have to send the data as `multipart/form-data` which means the video content. So to do this via ajax, I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery) on stackoverflow, and followed How to send FormData objects with Ajax-requests in jQuery.

Here's my **javascript code**:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append( 'source', 'https://cdn.whodaman.net/Q45rt7y.mp4' );
fd.append( 'access_token', testaccessToken);
fd.append( 'title', "Test Video");
$.ajax({
  url: "https://graph-video.facebook.com/"+testPageId+"/videos",
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data'); 
  }
});
```

Here's the request and corresponding response:

```
    Request URL:https://graph-video.facebook.com/[my page id]/videos
    Request Method:POST
    Status Code:400 Bad Request

    Request Headers
    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    Cache-Control:no-cache
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:948
    Content-Type:multipart/form-data
    Cookie: [some cookie data]
    Host:graph-video.facebook.com
    Origin:http://real.domain.com:8090
    Pragma:no-cache
    Referer:http://real.domain.com:8090/test/upload
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
    Request Payload
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryd8laVBo5HXRTFJnn
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"

    https://cdn.whodaman.net/Q45rt7y.mp4
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryd8laVBo5HXRTFJnn
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="access_token"

    [my access token]
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryd8laVBo5HXRTFJnn
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"

    Test Video
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryd8laVBo5HXRTFJnn--
    Response Headers
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
    Cache-Control:no-store
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:146
    Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Date:Mon, 11 Nov 2013 13:50:45 GMT
    Expires:Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
    Pragma:no-cache
    WWW-Authenticate:OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_token" "An access token is required to request this resource."
    X-FB-Debug:HlhHF7eIBkLbUBktqeWnVv8V3viIeS8jom0WPt1D7fc=
    X-FB-Rev:1000997
```

Facebook is asking for the access token! I'm pretty sure I have the right one, because I'm being able to add a text status post. I have also tried to change the name of the `file` parameter in form data from `source` to `file` to no effect.

So is it even possible to upload a video to facebook via the js sdk directly from the video url? I have a feeling it is, and am quite close to the solution.

Comment: _“which means the video content”_ – but you are _not_ uploading the video’s content, but only its URL here. For photos it is possible to upload them using the parameter `url` instead of `source` – so I’d try if that works for videos too. (Has to be a “normal” POST then, not multipart.)

Comment: But since facebook does not have a URL parameter for uploading video, this can't be done? I can't believe that, since uploading via an `input type='file'` technically does stream the data from a source.

Comment: I said I would _try_ that, I did not say it’s guaranteed to work. (The `url` parameter for photo uploads is barely documented either.) And maybe they designed the video upload feature mostly with “fresh” videos people would upload from their own device in mind, and not stuff that’s floating around the web already …

Comment: my videos are fresh! only that they have already been uploaded someplace else. i hope they come out with a url parameter soon.

Comment: @Atharva Johri i have same issue. u r solved this? if u find some solution please help to me.

Comment: @gokhan i used server side integration to accomplish this. If you are still interested, let me know and i'll point you to my github repo.

Comment: @Atharva Johri  yes i'm interesting. be pleased thanks.

Comment: @AtharvaJohri i'm still waiting your return. i found your github account when u upload please write. Thanks bro.

Comment: @AtharvaJohri when u will be free dude. i still wait u. :)

Comment: @gokhan hey - check out the `uploadMediaToFacebook` method here https://github.com/atharvajohri/minerva/blob/master/Minerva/grails-app/controllers/com/minerva/MediaController.groovy

I am making use of restfb, and expecting the access token in the request

Comment: @AtharvaJohri u have skype?

Comment: Hi @gokhan - i have shown you the code and told you the steps.. try solving the problem yourself now - it is not that difficult :)

Answer (score 4):

Perform a POST request to the graph api Using the file_url field to specify the url for your video and get rid of the source field , no need for a multipart/form-data .

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this answer, and why; it should be the accepted one.

Comment: Can you show me how? Im not web developer. I need it for my Unity standalone game.